# Where in with array of values MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby

Lets say of I have this query `SELECT * FROM table WHERE id IN (1,2,3,4);`

In my current use case my ids are in an array like so `[1,2,3,4]`

How could I do the same query using the array data structure?

i.e. `SELECT * FROM table WHERE id IN (myarray);`

Edit: this is in ruby :)

Comment: Are you using activerecord?

Comment: What SQL query library are you using?

Comment: yes using activerecord base execute

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

`SELECT * FROM table WHERE id IN (myarray.map {|i| "\"#{i}\""}.join(", "));`

Comment: Similar to @urielSilva answer, but this will work for both integers and strings

Comment: what can I do if my string : `SELECT * FROM table WHERE id IN (?);`

Answer (score 1):

You could convert the array to a comma separated string using the `myarray.join(',')` method.

The final code would look like this:

```
query = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE id IN (#{myarray.join(',')})"
```

You might run into some problems if the array values are strings, but it works just fine for integers.

Answer (score 1):

```
User.where(id: [1, 2, 3, 4, nil]).to_sql
# SELECT "users".* FROM "users"
# WHERE ("users"."id" IN (1, 2, 3, 4) OR "users"."id" IS NULL)
```

or, if you can't/don't want to use `where`, you can drop into [Arel](https://github.com/rails/arel) to get just the IN string:

```
User.arel_table[:id].in([1,2,3,4]).to_sql
# => "users"."id" IN (1, 2, 3, 4)
```

though with this, you don't automatically get that nifty `nil` handling. If you don't have an ActiveRecord Model, but just using `ActiveRecord::Base` to execute queries in your database (as mentioned in the [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45576836/where-in-with-array-of-values-mysql/45577204?noredirect=1#comment-78113241)) you can do:

```
table = Arel::Table.new(:table) # :table is the name of the table in db
table[:id].in([1,2,3,4]).to_sql
# => "table"."id" IN (1, 2, 3, 4)
table.where(table[:id].in([1,2,3,4])).project(Arel.sql('*')).to_sql
# => SELECT * FROM "table" WHERE "table"."id" IN (1, 2, 3, 4)
```

And, avoiding Arel/ActiveRecord as much as possible, you can just do

```
ActiveRecord::Base.send(:sanitize_sql, ['id in (?)', [1,2,3,4]])
# => "id in (1,2,3,4)"
```

Comment: You get a +1 for suggesting an `arel` solution which is probably the must under leveraged library in all of `rails` (from a developer perspective not an internals perspective *it works hard internally*)

Comment: Very nice.  I would like to stray away from actually using the ActiveRecord syntax.  Straight sql would be preferred.